# Redirecting stdin and stdout in scala

Tags: scala

How can I redirect STDIN and STDOUT to files?

In C, this would be done like so:

```
freopen("file.in","r",stdin);
```

I am looking for something equivalent for Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using the Java System api.
The code is nearly identical for Java and Scala:

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream("file.in"))
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("file.out")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like:

```
import java.io.File
import scala.sys.process._
"cat" #< new File("file.in") !
```

source: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.sys.process.package