# Store execution plan of Spark´s dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am currently trying to store the execution plan of a Spark´s dataframe into HDFS (through dataframe.explain(true) command)

The issue I am finding is that when I am using the explain(true) command, I am able to see the output by the command line and by the logs, however if I create a file (let´s say a .txt) with the content of the dataframe´s explain the file will appear empty.

I believe the issue relates to the configuration of Spark, but I am unable to 
find any information about this in internet

(for those who want to see more about the plan execution of the dataframes using the explain function please refer to https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-dataset-operators.html#explain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I create a file (let´s say a .txt) with the content of the dataframe´s explain

How exactly did you try to achieve this?

`explain` writes its result to console, using `println`, and returns `Unit`, as can be seen in [Dataset.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L432):

```
def explain(extended: Boolean): Unit = {
  val explain = ExplainCommand(queryExecution.logical, extended = extended)
  sparkSession.sessionState.executePlan(explain).executedPlan.executeCollect().foreach {
    // scalastyle:off println
    r => println(r.getString(0))
    // scalastyle:on println
  }
}
```

So, unless you [redirect the console output to write to your file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34581147/5344058) (along with anything else printed to the console...), you won't be able to write `explain`'s output to file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is to redirect the output to a file when you run the job.  I have used the following command :

```
 spark-shell --master yarn -i test.scala > getlogs.log
```

my scala file has the following simple commands :

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testtable")
df.explain(true)
exit()
```