# How to save values in files instead of println?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, normalization

I want to save values into txtfile instead of println.

```
val movieMatrix = new RowMatrix(movieVectors) 
 val movieMatrixSummary =movieMatrix.computeColumnSummaryStatistics() 

val userMatrix = new RowMatrix(userVectors) 
val userMatrixSummary = userMatrix.computeColumnSummaryStatistics()
println("Movie factors mean: " + movieMatrixSummary.mean)
println("Movie factors variance: " + movieMatrixSummary.variance) 
println("User factors mean: " + userMatrixSummary.mean) 
println("User factors variance: " + userMatrixSummary.variance)
```

how to save values?

Comment: Maybe you are asking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581147/redirecting-stdin-and-stdout-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java `PrintWriter` or `FileWriter` to write values to a text file.

```
// PrintWriter
import java.io._
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("summary.txt" ))
pw.write("Movie factors mean: " + movieMatrixSummary.mean + "\n")
pw.close

// FileWriter
val file = new File(filepath)
val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
bw.write("Movie factors mean: " + movieMatrixSummary.mean + "\n")
bw.close()
```

It is generally better to use `FileWriter` as it throws `IOExceptions`, whereas `PrintWriter` doesn't throw exceptions, and instead sets Boolean flags that can be checked.

Comment: But i haven't file output after using computeColumnSummaryStatistics to calculate variance and mean.

Comment: Could you share more details on what you've tried so far? Did you try using `PrintWriter` or `FileWriter`?